# Cannot access error response body from client when using nginx + lua

Tags: ajax, http, nginx, lua

I'm using the following lua script to forward all server responses that are served from Node. My error handling for a `/signup` route works as follows:

```
if authenticationResult.status ~= 201 then
    ...

    ngx.status = authenticationResult.status
    ngx.say(authenticationResult.body)
    ngx.exit(401)
    return
end
```

From the client I send a typical signup request like so, using the `superagent-promise` library:

```
request
  .post(url)
  .type('form')
  .send(data)
  .end()
  .then((response) => {
    console.log('the response', response)
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log('the error', error)
  })
```

When I send a valid `post` request from the client, the `response` variable in the `.then` successfully contains the response body.

However, when I sent an improper `post` request with invalid credentials, *neither the .then nor the .catch executes.* Instead, the Chrome console immediately displays `POST http://api.dockerhost/signup 401 (Unauthorized)`.

I would like to know what I can do differently to successfully access the server's error response and its contents, outside of just its status code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [manual](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#ngxexit), you need to use `ngx.HTTP_OK` as the return if you want nginx to return content as part of the page. Otherwise it will simply return a 401.

```
ngx.status = authenticationResult.status
ngx.say(authenticationResult.body)
ngx.exit(ngx.HTTP_OK)
return
```